# ffmpeg unable to find encoder 'libvorbis'

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm unable to transcode a video file to webm because my machine isn't able to find libvorbis.  When I run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /public/uploads/tmp/1382112521-11953-7661/webm_Untitled.mov -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -s 640x360  -b 1500k -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 -aspect 1.7777777777777777 /public/uploads/tmp/1382112521-11953-7661/tmpfile.webm
```

I get the error

```
Unknown encoder 'libvorbis'
```

I already have libvorbis installed on my machine, though (When I try "brew install libvorbis, it tells me: Warning: libvorbis-1.3.3 already installed).

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the full log:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /public/uploads/tmp/1382112521-11953-7661/webm_Untitled.mov -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -s 640x360  -b 1500k -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 -aspect 1.7777777777777777 /public/uploads/tmp/1382112521-11953-7661/tmpfile.webm
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 18 2013 12:20:19 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/public/uploads/tmp/1382112521-11953-7661/webm_Untitled.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2013-09-27 20:08:57
  Duration: 00:00:02.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17460 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17292 kb/s, 29.88 fps, 29.83 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-27 20:08:57
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 123 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-27 20:08:57
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Unknown encoder 'libvorbis'
```

Answer (score 71):

Edit 2020:

Homebrew now installs libvorbis by default, so you can just run:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

---

If you're using Homebrew, try this:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-libvorbis
```

...or, if you've already tried installing ffmpeg with Homebrew...

```
brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvorbis
```

If you want libvpx, too:

```
brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvpx --with-libvorbis
```

Comment: The `--with-libvpx`  was required for proper webm conversion for me. It gave me this error, until i reinstalled with libvpx as @yndolok suggests:  `Encoder (codec vp8) not found for output stream`

Comment: Looks promising and a `brew info ffmpeg` indeed shows libvorbis wasn't installed by default. But when I try running these I get **Error: invalid option: --with-libvorbis** on Mojave using Homebrew 2.0.2. It seems the flag is not getting applied correctly for some reason in my shell.

Comment: I got this Error: invalid option: --with-libvpx

Answer (score 4):

Your ffmpeg build is not compiled with `--enable-libvorbis` which is required if you want libvorbis support in `ffmpeg`, but you have some options:

<sub>**Note:** Vorbis has been made obsolete by Opus, so consider using libopus instead–especially if you are encoding to [VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9)/[VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8) (WebM).</sub>

---

## Download a build

This is an easy option. Already compiled [macOS builds of ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#MacOSXBuilds) are available and come with libvorbis support. You can just download the executable and optionally put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

---

## Homebrew

#### Core

The [Hombrew core FFmpeg formulae](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ffmpeg.rb) contains support for libvorbis by default (as of 2019-03-01). First, [install Homebrew](https://brew.sh#install), then run:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

However, the core formulae no longer supports additional, non-default options such as `--with-aom`, so if you want to customize it see the option below.

#### homebrew-ffmpeg

This is a third-party tap that provides a Homebrew formula with lots of additional options you can enable. First, [install Homebrew](https://brew.sh#install), then:

1. Uninstall `ffmpeg` if you installed it from Homebrew core:

   ```
   brew uninstall ffmpeg
   ```
2. Then install ffmpeg from homebrew-ffmpeg:

   ```
   brew tap homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg
   brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
   ```

For more options and info see [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg).

---

## Compile

For complete instructions for manually compiling see [FFmpeg Wiki: macOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS).

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew [stopped supporting](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/ffmpeg-options-missing/3935) the `--with-libvorbis` option in late 2018. Precompiled binaries containing libvorbis for Linux, macOS and Windows here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed with the suggestion here of rebuilding ffmpeg using:

```
./configure --disable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvorbis; make; make install
```

http://xiphmont.livejournal.com/51160.html

Comment: Your link is a 404